# Add to List, javascript. Copying the value of textbox to another textbox using a button

Tags: javascript, html

> help. I want to make something like this, for example, ill put a price on textboxAdd and when i press the button, textbox1 will copy the value of textboxAdd(where the 1st price is there). then I'll put again, (2nd price) on textboxAdd and press the button, the value of textboxAdd (which is the 2nd price), it will be in textbox2. pls Help. Thank You.
>   My code is here and the output:

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<form>
    <table>
<tr><td>Add to list:</td><td><input type="text" name="addkist" value=""> </td></tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><input type="button" value="ADD TO LIST"></td>
</form>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> 
<th align="center" colspan="2" bgcolor="0033CC"><font color="white">Shopping LIST</font></th>
<tr><td ><center>No.</center></td><td ><center>Amount</center></td></tr>
<tr><td ><center>01</td><td><input class="total" type=text name=01></td></tr>
<tr><td ><center>02</td><td><input class="total" type=text name=02></td></tr>
<tr><td ><center>03</td><td><input class="total" type=text name=03></td></tr>
<tr><td ><center>04</td><td><input class="total" type=text name=04></td></tr>
<tr><td ><center>05</td><td><input class="total" type=text name=05></td></tr>
<tr><td ><center>06</td><td><input class="total" type=text name=06></td></tr>
<tr><td ><center>07</td><td><input class="total" type=text name=07></td></tr>
<tr><td ><center>08</td><td><input class="total" type=text name=08></td></tr>
<tr><td >TOTAL:</td><td align="center"> <span id="sum">0</span></td></tr>
</td></table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".total").each(function() 
    {
        $(this).keyup(function()
        {
            calculateSum();
        });
    });
});
function calculateSum() 
{
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".total").each(function() 
    {
        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) 
        {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
    </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: So you just want to copy the value from one textbox to another on button click?

Comment: yes. but on first click, the value will be on first textbox. on second click, the value will be on second textbox. on third click, it will be on third textbox, and so on. something like that. :(

Comment: This can be done but it's a bad approach because if you make a mistake in the order, you will be lost and have to wait till the textbox order is completed to redo. How about a dropdown specifying which textbox to add to?

Comment: its okay if its a bad approach. i'll try. coz, im not allowed to use other Form. only textbox. (thats what My professor wants) :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
// First let's put an ID attribute to recognize your button:
<input type="button" id="btn-add-to-list" value="ADD TO LIST">

// Next, Change your script code to:
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    num = 1; // this will be used to navigate to the next textbox

    $("#btn-add-to-list").click(function(){

                 // get the current value of the textbox
                val_to_add = $("input[name='addkist']").val(); 

                // checking if number is entered
                if(!isNaN(val_to_add) && val_to_add.length!=0) 
                {

                // clear the textbox to add to
                $("input[name='0"+num+"']").val('');

                // add the value of 'addkist' textbox to 'textbox 01, 02, 03' 
                // etc.in sequence
                $("input[name='0"+num+"']").val(val_to_add);

                // increment counter to go the next texbox
                num++;

                // if the last textbox reached, reset the counter
                if(num==9){num=1;}

                    calculateSum();
                }
            });
});
// this code of yours remains the way it was
function calculateSum() 
{
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".total").each(function() 
    {
        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) 
        {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
</script>
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SLH3J/)**

**Fiddle modified made as per the change in requirement mentioned in below comment:**
**[Fiddle Demo allowing commas](http://jsfiddle.net/SLH3J/1/)**

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger, i put Comma to the value in the textbox and it did not work. Can you help me. i want to calculate the value with comma. thank you.

Comment: @bellebelurbano The before code allowed only numbers, check out the second fiddle I've added that accepts commas too.

Comment: Thank Youuuuu so much :D loveyouuuu :)